# Split a value between startdate and enddate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL SERVER 2000.

I have a problem and dont know how to solve it :(

I have a table1:

| ID | start_date | end_date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 16:00 | 2021-06-15 14:00 | 5640 |
| 2 | 2021-06-11 08:00 | 2021-06-11 15:30 | 100 |

I need to get data from this table for a day, like this:

| ID | start_date | end_date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 16:00 | 2021-06-11 23:59 | 480 |
| 2 | 2021-06-11 08:00 | 2021-06-11 15:30 | 100 |

And the rest of the data should be splitted like this:

| ID | start_date | end_date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 16:00 | 2021-06-11 23:59 | 480 |
| 1 | 2021-06-12 00:00 | 2021-06-12 23:59 | 1440 |
| 1 | 2021-06-13 00:00 | 2021-06-13 23:59 | 1440 |
| 1 | 2021-06-14 00:00 | 2021-06-14 23:59 | 1440 |
| 1 | 2021-06-15 00:00 | 2021-06-15 14:00 | 840 |

So, for example, i need to get data for a day, the day is 2021-06-11 so qty should be 480, not empty and not 5640. I have to split the data somehow.

And again, sql server 2000...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server...?

Comment: SQL Server 2000?  Are you joking?  It hasn't been supported **at all** in something like a decade.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2000

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you have and what is the expected result. are you trying to use data from the first table, and the expected is the second table? can you explain the logic or provide another explanation like you did for 2021-06-11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
SELECT  T.id,

        -- new start_date: --
        CASE numTable.number
            WHEN  0
            THEN T.start_date
            ELSE DATEADD(
                    DAY,
                    numTable.number,
                    CAST(T.start_date AS DATE)
                )
        END,

        -- new end_date: --
        CASE numTable.number
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T.start_date, T.end_date)
            THEN T.end_date
            ELSE DATEADD(
                    DAY,
                    numTable.number + 1,
                    CAST(T.start_date AS DATE)
                )
        END,

        -- new qty: --
        DATEDIFF(
            HOUR,
            CASE numTable.number
                WHEN  0
                THEN T.start_date
                ELSE DATEADD(
                        DAY,
                        numTable.number,
                        CAST(T.start_date AS DATE)
                    )
            END,
            CASE numTable.number
                WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T.start_date, T.end_date)
                THEN T.end_date
                ELSE DATEADD(
                        DAY,
                        numTable.number + 1,
                        CAST(T.start_date AS DATE)
                    )
            END
            )
        * T.qty / DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.start_date, T.end_date)


FROM    table1                  AS  T
JOIN    master.dbo.spt_values   AS  numTable
ON      numTable.type           =   'p'
AND     numTable.number         <=  DATEDIFF(DAY, T.start_date, T.end_date)
```

Comment: As i stated above. If a record appears in like  2021-06-11 16:00(startdate) and ends 2021-06-12 13:00 (enddate). This is 1 record in database. It should be splitted in 2 records. Like this - 1st record 2021-06-11 16:00(startdate) - 2021-06-11 23:59(enddate) and 2nd record 2021-06-12 00:00(startdate) - 2021-06-12 13:00(enddate). Your solution gives me wrong startdate and enddate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only problem I see is the in end-date- it shows the next day on 00:00:00 instead of the same day on 23:59:59, if so, you just need to deduct 1 second from the new end_date field on the else statement